# Push an object multidimension array object javascript

Tags: javascript

please help me.
i got problem when i want to push object into my existing array object. please tell me if there is similar question like this.

this is my code :

```
var menu = [{
  "id": 1,
  "text": "menu 1",
  "parent": "-",
  "child": {}
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "text": "menu 3",
  "parent": "-",
  "child": {}
}];

var menuchild = [{
  "id": 2,
  "parent": 1,
  "text": "menu 2"
},
{
  "id": 5,
  "parent": 3,
  "text": "menu 5"
},
{
  "id": 6,
  "parent": 1,
  "text": "menu 6"
}];

$.each(menuchild, function(key, value) {

  let item = {
    'id': value.id,
    'text': value.text,
    'parent': value.parent
  }

let parentindex = menu.findIndex(el => el.id === value.parent);

// if i use this return error push is not a function
menu[parentindex]['child'].push(item) 

// if i use this the data wil be replace if there is 2 object with same parent
menu[parentindex]['child'] = item

})
```

please tell me what is the best way to push the data ?

Comment: You are trying to push to an javascript object, rather push is a fucntion on javascript array s. Also variable parent is not clear in the question.

Comment: what do you mean push function ?
i think my question declaration is good enough, sorry.

Comment: parent[parentindex]['child'].push(item) the variable parent is not defined, where does it come. And the push(item) is a function in javascript arrays not objects.

Comment: sorry, actually the parent variable is menu, i forget to change the code when i create the question. i already fix my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `child` of `menu` to be an `object` then below will be the way.

```js
var menu = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'menu 1',
    parent: '-',
    child: {},
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'menu 3',
    parent: '-',
    child: {},
  },
];

var menuchild = [
  {
    id: 2,
    parent: 1,
    text: 'menu 2',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    parent: 3,
    text: 'menu 5',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    parent: 1,
    text: 'menu 6',
  },
];

let updatedParents = menuchild.map(ch => {
  childParent = menu.find(m => m.id === ch.parent)
  return {
    ...childParent,
    child: {...ch}
  }
});

console.log(updatedParents)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

But, if want the `child` of `menu` array to be an `array`, then below is the way to achieve the output you are looking for.

```js
var menu = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'menu 1',
    parent: '-',
    child: [],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'menu 3',
    parent: '-',
    child: [],
  },
];

var menuchild = [{
    id: 2,
    parent: 1,
    text: 'menu 2',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    parent: 3,
    text: 'menu 5',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    parent: 1,
    text: 'menu 6',
  },
];


const finalResult = menuchild.reduce((result, ch) => {
  let index = result.findIndex(r => r.id === ch.parent);
  result[index].child.push(ch);
  return result;
}, [...menu])

console.log(finalResult)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Happy to have helped you :)